# How to display error message for dynamic form fields (react + formik + yup)

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I tried to display the error message for dynamic inputs by using onBlur to determine whether the input has been touched or not. But the error message is not being displayed.

```
<Form.Control
   className={
      touched.quantity &&
      errors.quantity
      ? "error"
      : null
   }
   name={`item.${index}.quantity`}
   type="number"
   value={item.quantity || ""}
   onBlur={handleBlur}
   onChange={handleChange}
   required                                                
/>

{touched.quantity &&
errors.quantity ? (
<div className="error-message">
   {errors.quantity}
</div>
) : null}
```